# Foreign key referential integrity in the fact tables - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, etl, data-warehouse, fact-table

I have this fact table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FACT_TABLE]
(
    [A_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [B_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [D_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FACT_total] [float] NOT NULL,
    [FACT_average] [float] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FACT_TABLE] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([A_id] ASC, [B_id] ASC,
                               [C_id] ASC, [D_id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a T-SQL Script to load data into my fact table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FACT_TABLE] ([A_id], [B_id], [C_id], [company_id], [D_id],[FACT_total], [FACT_average])
    SELECT 
        b.A_id, c.B_id, d.C_id, e.D_id,
        AVG(FACT_total) AS FACT_total,
        AVG(FACT_average) AS FACT_average
    FROM 
        [dbo].[staging_Area] a
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DIM_A] b ON a.A_id = b.A_id
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DIM_B] c ON a.[B_id] = c.B_id
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DIM_C] d ON a.[C_id] = d.C_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DIM_D] e ON a.D_id = e.D_id
    GROUP BY  
        b.A_id, c.B_id, d.C_id, e.D_id
```

How can I guarantee that I don't insert duplicate values in my fact table in order to not get referential integrity error?

I tried with the following statement after that query:

```
EXCEPT 
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[FACT_TABLE]
```

But I think that isn't the best approach for this...

Anyone have another alternative for this? Sorry but I can't put the real column and tables names...

Thanks!

Comment: how do you define your duplicates? if it is the entire record, put all the columns as composite key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `WHERE FT.Column IS NULL` to Fact table to ensure you're not inserting a record that already exists:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FACT_TABLE] ([A_id],[B_id],[C_id],[company_id],[D_id],[FACT_total],[FACT_average])
SELECT b.A_id
        ,c.B_id
        ,d.C_id
        ,e.D_id
        ,AVG(FACT_total) AS FACT_total
        ,AVG(FACT_average) AS FACT_average
FROM [dbo].[staging_Area] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DIM_A] b ON
    a.A_id = b.A_id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DIM_B] c ON
    a.[B_id] = c.B_id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DIM_C] d ON
    a.[C_id] = d.C_id 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DIM_D] e ON
    a.D_id = e.D_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[FACT_TABLE] FT
    ON b.A_ID = FT.A_id
    AND c.B_id = FT.B_id
    AND D.C_ID = FT.C_id
    AND E.D_id = FT.D_id
WHERE FT.A_ID IS NULL
GROUP BY  b.A_id
        ,c.B_id
        ,d.C_id
        ,e.D_id
```

Comment: Actually, the `DISTINCT` is redundant.  Since you're already grouping, you can't get duplicates.  I will edit the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FACT_TABLE]

([A_id], [B_id], [C_id], [D_id],[FACT_total], [FACT_average])

select a.A_id, a.B_id, a.C_id, a.D_id,a.FACT_total,a.FACT_average

from

( 
SELECT

```
b.A_id, c.B_id, d.C_id, e.D_id,
AVG(FACT_total) AS FACT_total,
AVG(FACT_average) AS FACT_average
```

FROM

```
[dbo].[staging_Area] a
```

INNER JOIN

```
[dbo].[DIM_A] b ON a.A_id = b.A_id
```

INNER JOIN

```
[dbo].[DIM_B] c ON a.[B_id] = c.B_id
```

INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[DIM_C] d ON a.[C_id] = d.C_id

INNER JOIN

```
[dbo].[DIM_D] e ON a.D_id = e.D_id
```

GROUP BY

```
b.A_id, c.B_id, d.C_id, e.D_id 

)a
```

where

NOT EXISTS

(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbao.FACT_TABLE B

WHERE
B.A_id = A.A_id AND B.B_id = A.B_id and b.C_id=a.C_id and b.D_id=a.D_id

```
   )
```

Comment: You should work on formatting this, @alen - it's practically unreadable.